# Removing space from values while reading Tab file using oledbconnection

Tags: c#

### Following is the content of my tab file

```
 Id         ScenarioName                                    MainBatchName               Variable                                    Value   French  Dutch   Italian     Remarks     Project             SubProject          EnvDBQuery
 26345935   85036_Self_Service_API_RedeemRewardsRequest     <LMR_AccountNumber@1_1>     "[PC_AccNum]_2"                             ""      ""      ""      ""          BankCard    CreditProcessing    ""
 26345936   85036_Self_Service_API_RedeemRewardsRequest     <LMR_AccountNumber@1_2>     "[PC_AccNum]_1"                             ""      ""      ""      ""          BankCard    CreditProcessing    ""
 26328357   85036_Self_Service_API_RedeemRewardsRequest     <RRR_MessageVal@1_1>        "Loyalty points processed successfully "    ""      ""      ""      ""          BankCard    CreditProcessing    ""
 26328358   85036_Self_Service_API_RedeemRewardsRequest     <RRR_MessageVal@1_2>        "Loyalty points processed successfully "    ""      ""      ""      ""          BankCard    CreditProcessing    ""
```

I used the following code snippet to read the content of the tab

```
string fileName = "abc.tab";
string directoryName = @"D:\myDirectory\";
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + directoryName + @";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;FMT=TabDelimited;CharacterSet=65001""";

OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand();
DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);


   oleCmd.Connection = conn;
   conn.Open();

   oleCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + fileName + "]";
   dataAdapter.SelectCommand = oleCmd;

   CreateSchemaFile("TabDelimited", directoryName, fileName);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataTbl);
```

After the fill method is called, the datatable is having the values "*Loyalty points processed successfully*" instead of "*Loyalty points processed successfully* "

It is removing the space from the end of the string value if any.

What should be done so that the value is read as it is present in the tab file?

Comment: Not pretty but will work :            foreach (DataRow row in dataTbl.AsEnumerable())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataTbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = row[i].ToString().Trim();
                }
            }

Comment: My data table contain values where spaces are getting removed. But I want to keep the spaces if any present.

Comment: Trim will do that.  It just removes the spaces from the beginning and end of the strings, not in the middle.

Comment: But I don't want to remove the spaces. I want the values with the spaces even if they are at the beginning or end or both

Comment: WHY???? Not the usual way of handling strings.  If you need space added later in code add the spaces.  Right now you aren't matching the values due to the spaces.

Comment: How can I add space if I don't know how much space can be there or for which value space would be there as my data is not fixed. It can change any time.

Comment: If it is columns are in a database or a control like a DGV you set the column width, you do not use the length of the string in the column.  String you do not keep the spaces at the beginning and end so you don't have issues when search for the string.  How do you know when a space is at the beginning or end of a string?

Comment: I think you are going in wrong direction. I need to retain the spaces(beginning, end, both) in the values as it is the requirement.

Comment: Are you sure that is it needed in the control?  Very unusual request.  The tab delimited file needs the spaces but not the datatable.

Comment: This has come up many times - its a known issue the end spaces are always removed, that oledb will trim spaces - google